# anyone know of a custom membership provider implementation that check password strength against in-built dictionary

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I've got an Asp.net MVC app and before being able to go live, the IT have requested for us to comply with their password policy. The flexibility of AspnetSqlMembershipProvider doesn’t quite satisfy the requirement.

The password strength and length rules are as follows:

- one lowercase
- one Uppercase
- one number and or special character
- 8 characters in length

so far, aspnetsqlmembershipprovider is good...

Not allowed to use:

- Dictionary words Names, real or
- fictional Plain language phrases
- Dates
- Telephone numbers
- Car registration numbers
- User IDs
- Postal codes
- Organization name

Only the first 4 criteria are satisfied by the aspnetsqlmembershipprovider. Do you know of any third party products that offers this functionality (preferably in the form of a custom membership provider)?

Comment: Upon further discussion, IT have clarified that the second part of the policy is a human process policy and does not have to be enforced programmaticaly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no need to change the membership provider, rather you can put same jquery validations to ensure the rules you would like to implement.
Kindly have a look at following,

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-password-strength-meter-scripts-for-a-better-registration-interface/

Hope this helps

Comment: good point. But unfortunately it's a company policy to have this policy enforced server side.